# Replace first occurance of char with * then the rest with a ' '

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence (this is a dumb example sentence ) that looks like this:

```
I_like_to_program__.
```

I need a function to make it look like this:

```
I*like to program.
```

I have written this expression:

```
var myExpression = new RegExp("\\_", "g");
return myString.replace(myExpression, " ").trim();
```

That'll output: `"I like to program."` --I'm close. I just need the first space to replace with a * to make it look like `I*like to program.`

Comment: Well, as you know(?) if you don't pass a regex to replace, it will only replace the first instance of the searchString with the replaceString...

Comment: What are the rules for the `_`. It appears as though some are not being replace with a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't add `g`, javascript's replace default to only one replacement :

```
return myString.replace(/\__/, "").replace(/\_/, "*").replace(/\_/g, " ");
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Notice the pair of underscores before the period? Yours spits out "I*like to program  ."

Answer (score 8):

```
mystring.replace("_", "*")
        .replace(/_/g, " ");
```

Or you could avoid the regex altogether like this:

```
mystring.replace("_", "*")
        .split("_")
        .join(" ");
```

Comment: @pst: Probably thinking of `String.prototype.match()`, which does do the conversion. :)

Comment: Nope - ouputs "I*like to program ."

Comment: @enhzflep: This is an example string. What are the rules that govern which `_` should be replaced with a space, and which should removed? I've only answered the part of the question that is answerable.

Comment: @user1689607 Ahh: `program__.` needs to become `program.` .. I suppose.

Comment: @pst: Yes, but we really don't know what attributes of those underscores make them stand out as needing special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can think of is to do it in two steps-- replace the first instance with *, then iterate again and replace globally with " "

```
var myString = "I_LIKE_TO_PROGRAM";
var myExpression = new RegExp("\_");
myString = myString.replace(myExpression, "*").trim();
var newExpression = new RegExp("\_", "g");
alert(myString.replace(newExpression, " ").trim());
```

Comment: Bzzz - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: Good calling me on not actually paying attention to my code... copy/paste is not always the answer! Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = "I_like_to_program__.";
var result =  myString.replace(/\_/g, " ").replace("  ", "").replace(" ", '*');
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I first replace all _ replace with "", after doing this in we we will have program .
So In second replace I am removing (program .) this space and in third replace I put * in first place.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/QV9qH/

Comment: Does not work right if there is a space before `_`, like this: `I so_like_to_program__.`

Comment: Ya I tried with space then _ its not working. trying to edit the fiddle.